# Silent Push Notification is not received to the device in swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, silentpush

When I send the notification. I am getting the notification randomly on the devices.
I was sending notification to 5 devices. Now 3 devices were receiving the notification and 2 device didn't received.

- When the app is running in the foreground I am getting notification in all devices.
- When app is in background I am getting notifications.
- When app is killed by the user and even phone is locked I didn't receive any notification in couple of devices and received in other device.

Now, when I open the app I immediately received the notification.
I read an article from apple doc on silent push notification and there it is clearly mentioned that there is no guarantee of notification delivery to the device.

I cannot use normal notifications because I am filtering data before the notification shown to user. If payload have device id which is equal to stored device id then I fired a local notification if not then notification is silent.
Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score -2):

You can use UNNotificationServiceExtension which allows modification of a remote notification content before its delivered to the user. Here is the reference link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

Comment: But I am not getting notification from apple server itself. It is not delivered to the app so how can I use UNNotificationServiceExtension @MeghaJain?